# javascript to display loading image

Tags: javascript, python, cgi, loading

I am trying to display a "loading image" while some processing is happening in background.Following code is not hiding the "loading image" once the page is loaded.Is there something wrong in this code?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# Create instance of FieldStorage
import cgi
import subprocess
import re
import sys
import os
print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
print
print "<html>"
print "<head>"
print "<title>Hello - Second CGI Program</title>"
print "</head>"
print '''
<style>
#loading{
width: 50%;
height: 50%;
top: 0;
left: 0;
position: fixed;
display: block;
opacity: 0.7;
background-color: #fff;
z-index: 99;
text-align: center;
}

#loading-image {
position: absolute;
top: 50px;
left: 140px;
z-index: 100;
}
</style>
<body>
<div id="loading">
<img id="loading-image" src='../images/loader.gif' alt='Loading...' />
</div>'''

form = cgi.FieldStorage(){
    # Get data from fields
    left: 140px;
    z-index: 100;
}
</style>

<body>
<div id="loading">
  <img id="loading-image" src='../images/loader.gif' alt='Loading...' />
</div>'''

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
# Get data from fields
#caseid=form.getvalue('case',default=None)
#filename=form.getvalue('filename',default=None)
caseid='CASE1'
filename='READ.txt'
pathtofile='/var/www/py_files/'+caseid+'/'+filename
#print('PATH TO FILE'+pathtofile)
destpath='/var/PacketPro/'+caseid+'/'+filename
#print('DEST PATH'+destpath)
#result=filetransfer(pathtofile,destpath)
#print('Result'+str(result))
#sys.exit(0)
#print output
print '''

<h2>Hello  </h2>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
  $('#loading').hide();
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>'''
```

Comment: Are you missing a jQuery reference ?

Comment: ok.I added it now.Basically this script is the form action script for my html page.

Comment: Is it working now ?

Comment: ok.I added it now.Basically this script is the form action script for my html page.Once i submit the html page i expect this script to load and display the image until rest of contents is generate by the page.But that does not seem to be happening.Its directly displaying the contents now instead of the image and html page is in loading state until entire content is generated

Answer (score 0):

if you replace the

```
$('#loading').hide();
```

with

```
$('#loading').css("display","none");
```

then the tag should have it's display style set to none, which will hide it.

if you wish to have the style put back to normal at anytime, then use

```
$('#loading').css("display","block");
```

apologies if there is a better way of doing this in jQuery, I must admit that I have not used it much so am not overly familiar with it